# Rails 4: order model by latest date of child

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In Rails 4, I have a model `Thread` which `has_many` `Emails`. Each `Email` has a field named `internal_date`. I want to return a collection of threads, ordered in a way where the thread with the latest `email.internal_date` comes first (very similar to how Gmail would sort its inbox).

This is the current line in my controller (not ordering them so far):

`@threads = selected_threads.joins(:tags).filter(params_filters).includes(:emails, [some other stuff]).distinct.all.paginate(page: params[:page], :per_page => 10)`

I'm doing the `joins` because of the filtering; and using `includes` to speed things up.

Ideally I would add a scope `order_by_latest_email` to my `Thread` model, without killing the loading time with too many DB queries. Any tips?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is only possible with a really ugly query like so:

```
Thread.joins(:emails)
  .select('threads.*, emails.internal_date')
  .joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN emails em ON (emails.internal_date < em.internal_date and emails.thread_id = em.thread_id)')
  .where('em.id IS NULL').order('emails.internal_date DESC')
  # additional filters here
```

You can see details in a blog post [here](http://www.peterdebelak.com/blog/posts/complex-activerecord-queries-pt-ii-greatest-n-per-group/), but this is a semi common sql problem known as the greatest n per group.

You need to find the latest email internal date in the group of emails connected to a thread. So what you do is:

1. compare all the emails with each other
2. continue until you find one where no other email (where `em` represents that other email) has a later `internal_date` (that's what the `em.id IS NULL` is doing)
3. order by that email's `internal_date`.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for! Pity we need such an ugly query though.

Comment: Thanks! You save my day.